# How to check if number is a decimal and run function laravel

Tags: laravel

I use Ajax to search my data and when it runs it removes price formatting from 49.99 to 4999. I can solve the problem by using `${{number_format($product->price / 100, 2)}}`  in the view file but the problem is if the price is displaying correctly as 49.99 and the function runs then it now displays as 0.50. How can I run a check so that this function only attempts to format price if it doesn't have decimal, only if its a int like 4999

I tried

```
            if(is_float($product->price)){
                echo $product->price;
            } else {
                echo number_format($product->price / 100, 2);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
if (is_numeric($product->price) && floor($product->price) != $product->price) {    
                echo $product->price;
            } else {
                echo number_format($product->price / 100, 2);
            }
```